# Solving complex trig functions: $\sin2x + \sin3x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

How to solve:

$$\sin(2x) + \sin(3x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
where $x$ is in $[-\pi,\pi]$?

I have no idea what to do with the $\sin(2x) + \sin(3x)$.

Am I supposed to factorise, differentiate, is there some theory I am to apply?

Comment: Is my edit correct? Your text didn't make clear if the number is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ or $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: the first one :)

Comment: How about introduce complex numbers, solve the cubic using Cardano's method, and then... Just kidding.

Comment: Try tan(x/2)=t.

Comment: where did then tan come from and the t.?

i have no idea where you pulled that from. :/

Comment: It will yield a 6th degree polynomial... Seems fine?

Comment: this is making no sense

Comment: 1 solution is $n\pi-\frac 2 3 \pi$

Comment: i dont want the answer, i need an intro into solving this problem. where do i begin

Comment: @Awesome I agree with you, it will form 6th degrees polynomial. This is really difficult. I only found 2 roots: $\dfrac\pi3$ and $-\dfrac{2\pi}3$.

Comment: Other solutions are not easy. Other one is : http://www5a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP6571fbe16d7b14e145000002e1fggf5bchfe4fd?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=9&w=580.&h=329.

Comment: im assuming there must be an easier method because this part of an intro course in trig.

can someone please explain the method of solving?

Comment: What is the answer given? Maybe this was a typo. Or they expect you to find only 1 family of solution.

Comment: it is:

x= -6.1, -5.2, -2.09,-1.51,0.1799, 1.047, 4.188,4.77

(approx)

Comment: But you stated that $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: Since this is only intro course, I wonder what kind of class did you take? Olympiad or Putnam prep?

Comment: Are you sure you can't just graph the function $f(x)=\sin2x+\sin3x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and use a graphing calculator to approximate the $x$-intercepts?

Comment: funny, those answers appear to be out of the domain.. :/ 

so is there a method to solve this by hand? and then perform the rest of the calculations by CAS?

Answer (score 2):

The angle addition formulas

$$\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\sin(3x)&=\sin x\cos(2x)+\cos x\sin(2x)\\
&=\sin x(2\cos^2x-1)+2\cos^2x\sin x\\
&=\sin x(4\cos^2x-1)
\end{align}$$

turn the equation $\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)=\sqrt3/2$ into $s(4c^2+2c-1)=\sqrt3/2$, where $s$ and $c$ abbreviate $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.  Squaring both sides and replacing $s^2$ with $1-c^2$ leads to a polynomial expression in $c$:

$$(1-c^2)(4c^2+2c-1)^2={3\over4}$$

It's easy to check that $c=\pm{1\over2}$ satisfies this equation, corresponding to the solutions $x=\pi/3$ and $-2\pi/3$ noted by Tunk-Fey in comments.  (There are, of course, *two* values of $x$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ for each value of $c$, but you have to go back to the *unsquared* equation to get the angle with the correct sign for $s$.)  The polynomial expression in $c$, expanded and factored, is

$$(2c-1)(2c+1)(16c^4+16c^3-16c^2-16c+1)=0$$

The quartic factor has two real roots, both in $[0,1]$, neither of which is the cosine of any nice angle.  I get $c\approx0.0592136551698$ and $c\approx0.983859187765$ for the other roots, with $s\approx-0.99824533209$ and $s\approx0.178944401$ as the corresponding values of $s=\sin x$.  These correspond to $x\approx-0.481140676\pi$ and $x\approx0.0572682233\pi$.

The unpleasantry of the quartic factor makes me wonder about the context of the problem.  Could it have just been asking to find *a* solution?

Answer (score 0):

(This is not a complete answer.)

Consider the function
$$f(x):=\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)-{\sqrt{3}\over2}\ .$$
Since we can guess the zeros ${\pi\over3}$ and ${4\pi\over 3}$ it makes sense to introduce the function
$$g(y):=f\left({\pi\over3}+y\right)\ .$$
Indeed, after some computation one obtains
$$g(y)=-\sin y\>\bigl(\cos y+\sqrt{3}\sin y+3\cos^2 y-\sin^2 y\bigr)\ .$$
Unfortunately the second factor cannot be reduced in a simple way.